# Can't connect python (Flask) with Mysql container using docker-compose

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose creating a container with python / Flask and mysql. I'm trying to connect both containers. I run the docker-compose and then I execute a file with the connector, but it shows the error:

**mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (99)**

This are my files:

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  api:
    build: ops/ubuntu/
    command: ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./gots
        target: /code
        read_only: false
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - FLASK_APP=app.py
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./ops/database/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

*Ubuntu image*

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code

# Install apt dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    vim \
    wget \
    software-properties-common \
    curl

# Install Python libraries
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then I'm trying to create the connection with this file:

*database_connector.py*

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector

ENV : str = '.env'
STATIC_FOLDER : str = '/code/static'
csv_name : str = 'Anexo6_CLP_sus_harm - Pandas-Ready_AnnexVI_CLP_Table3_Sep_2018.csv'

df : pd.core.frame.DataFrame = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(STATIC_FOLDER, csv_name))

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host = os.getenv(('HOST_IP'), 'localhost'), # awk 'END{print $1}' /etc/hosts
  user = os.getenv(('MYSQL_USER'), 'user'),
  password = os.getenv(('MYSQL_PASSWORD'), 'password'),
  database = os.getenv(('MYSQL_DATABASE'), 'database')
)

print('It worked...')
```

But here I'm always getting the same error:

mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (99)

Any help about what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use the other container's name `mysql` as a hostname; `localhost` in Docker usually means "this container".

Comment: It might be also useful to use
depends_on:
      - mysql
in your api container to make sure mysql container will complete startup before api launches

Comment: It solved! The problem was using localhost instead of mysql. Didn't know it work like this. Thanks! :)